# how do I activate/deactivate predictive text for input fields on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have:

```
<input type="text" />
```

i want to turn off predictive text using Javascript or any code automatically without need to go to settings and turn it off, so any one can help me ?

Comment: Please provide your code...

Comment: Why would you do that? How is it useful to users to disable this?

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan because when you enable XT9 and write in any input the letters u typed don't appear at inputanother reasone is that my native language not english so sometimes i write english letters but it is not english language

Comment: `<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">` should do it, but in Samsung Galaxy Tab Firefox 39.0 it doesn't work, so I had to manually disable predictive text in Settings - Controls - Samsung Keyboard Settings - Smart Typing - Predictive Text.

Comment: Is there any solution for samsung device to turn off predective text from HTML page programmatically ?

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced this as well.

Try this

```
<input type="text" name="some_name" autocorrect="off">
```

[Read this for more details](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/autocomplete-off/)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but HTML5 introduces a bunch of new input types such as "email", "url", "search", etc. Using the best semantic "type" and then allowing the platform to make the decision of how to handle that type is generally better practice than changing the behavior of the input type in a way that will be inconsistent with how the platform generally handles that kind of input.

Comment: it isn't about type!! because i have many inputs with different types and all of them support the autocomplete

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery you can do something like this:

```
    // using a JavaScript object literal to change multiple attributes at once:
      $(document).find('input')
                 .attr({
                      autocorrect: 'off',
                      autocapitalize: 'off'
                  });
```

Comment: it was just an example showing you that you can set the attributes

Comment: W3 said nothing about `autocomplete` either, until browsers had already implemented it (due to credit card companies need foot secure transactions, allegedly).

Comment: @RPM i have test ur code it works on Iphone but on Samsung note does not work

Comment: Ugh, predictive/autocorrect text (ironically, I suppose). That should've been 'for,' not 'foot.' Dammit, autocorrect... XD

Comment: @DavidThomas i don't understand u !

Comment: @hero: what don't you understand?

Comment: @DavidThomas "That should've been 'for,' not 'foot.'"

Comment: That was merely a comment on my own previous comment.